# New sound when running QGIS 2.4

Tags: qgis

I used QGIS for a very long time.
In the last version, there seems be a new sound (buzz) when the program is run.
Does anybody know how we can remove this sound?

Comment: Is your problem related to this? https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10746